# Silex: sessions and closures

Tags: php, session, closures, silex

I have a problem with this code in Silex. I am programming a tiny webcart and i dont understand how session object works in Silex. This is my code and it always die with:

Fatal error: Function name must be a string session

In this lines:

```
$amount = $app['calculate_amount']($app['session']->get('cart'));
$items = $app['calculate_items']($app['session']->get('cart'));
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Cheers!

```
$app['calculate_amount'] = function ($cart) use ($app) {
$amount = 0.00;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?";
if(is_array($cart))
{
    foreach($cart as $id => $qty)
    {
        $product = $app['db']->fetchAssoc($sql, array($id));
        $amount += $product["price"]*$qty;

    }
}

    return $amount;
};



$app['calculate_items'] = function ($cart) {
$items = 0;
if(is_array($cart))
{
    foreach($cart as $id => $qty)
    {
        $items += $qty;
    }
}

return $items;
};

$app->before(function (Request $request) use ($app) {
if ($request->get('save') != NULL)
{

    foreach ($app['session']->get('cart') as $id_isbn => $qty)
    {
        if ($request->get('$id_isbn')=='0')
        {
            $app['session']->set('cart', array('$id_isbn' => NULL));
        }
        else
        {
            $app['session']->set('cart', array('$id_isbn' => $request->get('$id_isbn')));
        }
    }

    $amount = $app['calculate_amount']($app['session']->get('cart'));
    $items = $app['calculate_items']($app['session']->get('cart'));

    $app['session']->set('amount', $amount);
    $app['session']->set('items', $items);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the docs of Pimple, the DIC behind silex:

> Because Pimple sees anonymous functions as service definitions, you need to wrap anonymous functions with the protect() method to store them as parameter:

```
$container['random'] = $container->protect(function () { return rand(); });
```

[Direct link](https://github.com/fabpot/pimple#protecting-parameters).

So in short: pimple saw your anonymous functions as service definitions and ran them the first time you accessed them. You'll need to `protect()` them if you want to store the functions themselves for later retrieval.

Comment: Thanks! It works! The closures are new to me. You've been very helpful!